# How did the "reduce" function took the 1st element from the given "array" as it's "start" parameter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce, higher-order-functions, arrow-functions

Can anyone please explain the context here...

> If your array contains at least one element, you are allowed to leave off the start argument. The method will take the first element of the array as its start value and start reducing at the second element.

The below code is from https://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html#p_4TujL14aLE

```
function reduce(array, combine, start) {
    let current = start;
    for (let element of array) {
        current = combine(current, element);
    }
    return current;
}

console.log(reduce([1, 2, 3, 4], (a, b) => a + b, 0));
// → 10
```

I understood the above **console.log** expression since the parameters are obvious, but didn't understand the below one,

```
console.log([1, 2, 3, 4].reduce((a, b)  => a + b));
// → 10
```

*Thanks in advance...*

Comment: it's [documented here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#parameters) ... the *optional* initial value argument ... *A value to use as the first argument to the first call of the callbackFn. If no initialValue is supplied, the first element in the array will be used as the initial accumulator value and skipped as currentValue*

Comment: the top function `reduce` is not the same as the bottom one, `Array.prototype.reduce`

Comment: The `reduce` function whose code you got from eloquentjavascript.net is not the method that the quoted sentence refers to.

Comment: @Ajay - The book actually explains exactly what you're asking in the paragraph immediately after the code you've quoted. (It's definitely confusing; in Marijn's shoes, I would have named the one I put in the chapter differently to be clear it wasn't meant to be the same as `Array.prototype.reduce`.)

Comment: Documentation FTW!

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - so it is referencing to the ```Array.prototype.reduce``` from the documentation right ? I got little confused from your comment, (sry if I interpreted wrongly)

Comment: @AjayGovindSidharthan - No worries. The real `Array.prototype.reduce`, which is what `[1, 2, 3, 4].reduce((a, b)  => a + b)` uses, is *different from* the `reduce` function you quoted above from the book. The paragraph just after the function you quoted from the book explains that the real one will use the first element in the array if you don't specify an initial value (but the `reduce` function in the text does *not* do that). So using the name `reduce` for the function in the chapter is probably a bit confusing, I would have used something else (but writing books is *hard* :-) ).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder -  **.**